# Multiplication of three partial derivatives giving unexpected results.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Given the equation
$PV=nRT$
if we evaluate $\frac{\partial{P}}{\partial{V}} * \frac{\partial{V}}{\partial{T}} * \frac{\partial{T}}{\partial{P}}$ through taking all three partials and multiplying, we get $-1$. Why can we not cancel the fractions and get $1$ instead?

Answer (score 1):

When doing partial differentials, the terms are not unique.  That is, $\partial P$ is not a unique value, and means different things depending on what it is in ratio with.  In other words, the $\partial P$ in $\frac{\partial P}{\partial V}$ is a *different* term than the $\partial P$ in $\frac{\partial T}{\partial P}$.

To flesh this out a little more, the total differential of the ideal gas law is:

$$P\,dV + V\,dP = nR\,dT$$

A partial differential of $P$ with respect to $V$ happens when we only allow $P$ and $V$ to change.  That means the other differential, $dT$, is equal to zero (another way for saying that $T$ is not changing).  To keep track of these, we can subscript these partials with the variables that they are changing with:

$$P\,\partial_PV + V\,\partial_V\!P = 0 \\ 
\partial_V\!P = -\frac{P}{V}\partial_PV$$

Now, if you have the partial differential of $T$ with respect to $P$, you are now holding $V$ constant, so $dV = 0$.  That will give you the partial:

$$ V\,\partial_T\!P = nR\,\partial_PT  \\ 
\partial_T\!P = \frac{nR}{V}\,\partial_PT
$$

As you can see, $\partial_T\!P$ and $\partial_V\!P$ are two very different quantities with very different formulas!

Answer (score 1):

[Your result is right](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product_rule). Your intuition is for multiplying derivatives defined with the same quantities held fixed. But in your calculation, $\partial P/\partial V$ is on a surface of constant $T$ etc.

Comment: Why does this change anything? near a point, aren't all differentiable functions "flat" as in  they look like a line or in the 3 variable case a plane.

Comment: @AnonymousPerson If you approximate the constant-$T$, constant-$P$ and constant-$V$ surfaces with their tangent planes, these planes meet in at most one point, and almost any direction away from that point is in at most one of the planes.